# Is a reloadit card a scam?

Tags: sugar-daddy

I've been talking to this "sugar momma" because I always get added randomly. 10/10 times there fake. However, this is the first one that sent me a gift card and now wants me to get a reloadit card. Is this a scam?

Comment: Are you having sex with the "sugar momma" in exchange for money/favors? If not, it's a scam. Always.

Comment: "I've been talking to this "sugar momma".... [full stop] scam. Doesn't matter how that sentence ends.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The gift card is probably stolen and just used as bait to hook you in / make you think it's real.